# Learning pg_routing - shortest_path error

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting

I'm learning PostGIS and pg_routing to help in our project planning and grant applications at my transportation agency (we wanted to move beyond the limitations of the 1/4 mile walking buffer we use so frequently!).

I have been following [underdark's very helpful pg_routing tutorials](http://anitagraser.com/2011/02/12/drive-time-isochrones) but am having trouble running the shortest_path function in my own dataset:

```
function shortest_path(unknown, integer, bigint, boolean, boolean) does not exist
LINE 6:        SELECT * FROM shortest_path('
                             ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

CREATE TABLE catchment_facilities AS
SELECT
    id,
    the_geom,
    (SELECT sum(cost) FROM (
       SELECT * FROM shortest_path('
       SELECT objectid::int8 AS id,
          source::int4,
          target::int4,
          sweeptime::float8 AS cost
          FROM lionroute',
       55375,
       id,
       false,
       false)) AS foo ) AS cost
FROM lionroute_vertices_pgr;
```

From reading the forums I get the sense that one of my columns is not in the right format, but I can't for the life of me figure out which one ('id' is int8).

Comment: Thank you @dkastl you were right. The function I was looking for was pgr_dijkstra. I also needed to declare one of my columns as an integer for the function to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using an outdated tutorial with the new pgRouting 2.0 release, I guess.

As the error states, it cannot find the function, because the function has been renamed. I recommend you to look at the [pgRouting Workshop](http://workshop.pgrouting.org/).

The [pgRouting documentation](http://docs.pgrouting.org/2.0/en/doc/index.html) also gives brief examples for every function.